# How to get array data passed by .post in jquery into php?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem regarding on how to get the value of the array variable passed by `.post` in jquery into my php page

this is my jquery code:

```
minDate = [];
hoursWork = [];
empId = [];
        $('.minDate').each(function() { 
            minDate.push($(this).val());
        });

        $('.hoursWork').each(function() { 
            hoursWork.push($(this).val());
        });

        $('.empId').each(function() { 
            empId.push($(this).val());
        });

            $.post('rtInsert.php', { minDate: minDate, hoursWork: hoursWork, empId: empId }, function(data) { 
        alert(data);
    });
```

How can I get the passed data in my `rtInsert.php`

i tried

```
$minDate = $_POST['minDate'];
$empId = $_POST['empId'];
$workHours = $_POST['hoursWork'];
```

now how will i get the individual value of the array because all the 3 variables is an array

All I know is a single array using `foreach()` but
what if there are 3 arrays passed

Is there any idea how I can get it or how can I passed into single array.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you can't use `$_POST['blah']`, try [`file_get_contents("php://input")`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-descriptiop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `JSON.stringify(data);` to turn them into JSON and prase it on the server side as this; `$data = json_decode($json);`.

Your code will then become this:

```
var minDate = [];
var hoursWork = [];
var empId = [];
$('.minDate').each(function() { 
    minDate.push($(this).val());
});

$('.hoursWork').each(function() { 
    hoursWork.push($(this).val());
});

$('.empId').each(function() { 
    empId.push($(this).val());
});

$.post('rtInsert.php', { minDate: JSON.stringify(minDate), hoursWork: JSON.stringify(hoursWork), empId: JSON.stringify(empId) }, function(data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

And your server side ccode:

```
<?php
$mindate = json_decode($_POST['minDate']);
$hourswork = json_decode($_POST['hoursWork']);
$empid = json_decode($_POST['empId']);
foreach($mindate as $k=>$val)
{
    $date = $val;
    $work =$hourswork[$k];
    $id =$empid[$k];
    //...
}
?>
```